# How can I add class to the first and last item among the visible items of Owl Carousel 2?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I need to add a class to the first and last item of the currently visible items on Owl Carousel 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**DEMO:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/t9URfKq9Mwh9jO705h7u?p=preview

Owl carousel adds a class active to all the visible items. So as you can see I have written a script below to loop through all the owl-item with class active and then using the 0th and last index, I am adding two different classes.

Use the code in your project and you will get the classes added.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var carousel = $(".latest-work-carousel");
    carousel.owlCarousel({
        loop : true,
        items : 3,
        margin:0,
        nav : true,
        dots : false,
    });

    checkClasses();
    carousel.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
        checkClasses();
    });

    function checkClasses(){
        var total = $('.latest-work-carousel .owl-stage .owl-item.active').length;

        $('.latest-work-carousel .owl-stage .owl-item').removeClass('firstActiveItem lastActiveItem');

        $('.latest-work-carousel .owl-stage .owl-item.active').each(function(index){
            if (index === 0) {
                // this is the first one
                $(this).addClass('firstActiveItem');
            }
            if (index === total - 1 && total>1) {
                // this is the last one
                $(this).addClass('lastActiveItem');
            }
        });
    }


});
```

**DEMO:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/t9URfKq9Mwh9jO705h7u?p=preview

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: I have made a demo.

Comment: your code works fine but in my case, i want it to remain on the first and last active items even after scrolling the slider. like when you click on the next button, the first and last item changes right? i need our classes still to be on the visible items.

Comment: I was expecting this question. I will update the answer and demo.

Comment: I have updated the answer and demo. Please have a look.

Comment: this function only work on `single slider` it's possible this `function work` multiple slider

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same issue with styling the last active item and couldn't find anywhere for a easy fix. Finally came up with a fix that works for me.

Here's a simple fix that worked for me.

```
$('.owl-carousel')
  .on('changed.owl.carousel initialized.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $(event.target)
      .find('.owl-item').removeClass('last')
      .eq(event.item.index + event.page.size - 1).addClass('last');
  }).owlCarousel({
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 3,
      },
      768: {
        items: 4,
      },
    }
  });
```

First item can be easy styled just using css.

```
.owl-item:not(.active) + .owl-item.active{
   background: red;  
}
```

Comment: The JS doesn't work for me, selects the first active item instead of the last.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Lasithds answer, if you want to add "active" class to the first owl active div, you can use the following:

```
$('.owl-carousel').on('changed.owl.carousel initialized.owl.carousel', function (event) {
    $(event.target)
        .find('.owl-item').removeClass('first')
        .eq(event.item.index).addClass('first');
})
.owlCarousel({
    loop: false,
    dots: false,
});
```