# How to add class on the first & last element that has specific class inside multiple same elements class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add class on class on first & last child element with ONLY .active class. I found the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105651/how-can-i-add-class-to-the-first-and-last-item-among-the-visible-items-of-owl-ca):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var carousel = $(".latest-work-carousel");
    carousel.owlCarousel({
        loop : true,
        items : 3,
        margin:0,
        nav : true,
        dots : false,
    });

    checkClasses();
    carousel.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
        checkClasses();
    });

    function checkClasses(){
        var total = $('.latest-work-carousel .owl-stage .owl-item.active').length;

        $('.latest-work-carousel .owl-stage .owl-item').removeClass('firstActiveItem lastActiveItem');

        $('.latest-work-carousel .owl-stage .owl-item.active').each(function(index){
            if (index === 0) {
                // this is the first one
                $(this).addClass('firstActiveItem');
            }
            if (index === total - 1 && total>1) {
                // this is the last one
                $(this).addClass('lastActiveItem');
            }
        });
    }


});
```

It does work, however my problem is that the *firstActiveItem* class is only applied inside the first carousel and the *lastActiveItem* class inside second carousel.

How do i make it applies on all carousel regardless of how many carousel i have with same class?

Here's my complete code fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tarantadakadin101/xf54zsau/39/

Comment: Please note that `$('.latest-work-carousel .owl-stage .owl-item.active')` will return all the active items from all the carousels on the page (not from each carousel as you seem to expect).

Comment: Ohhhh, that's why it only adds the class on first & last carousel. I learn everyday, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `.owl-carousel` elements and find the target element from the current `.owl-carousel`'s children on every iteration. With this approach no matter how many carousels exists on the page. like this:

```
$('.owl-carousel').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.owl-stage .owl-item.active:first').addClass('firstActiveItem');
    $(this).find('.owl-stage .owl-item.active:last').addClass('lastActiveItem');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

the condition should be:

```
if (index === 0 || index === total / 2) {
      // this is the first one
      $(this).addClass('firstActiveItem'); // add class in first item
    }
    if ((index === total - 1 && total) > 1 || index === total / 2 - 1) {
      // this is the last one
      $(this).addClass('lastActiveItem'); // add class in last item
    }
```

here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/tarantadakadin101/xf54zsau/39/)

Comment: Thank you for answering but this only work on 2 carousel. It did worked when i changed "2" to the amount of carousel i have. Although it's not the answer im looking for, it might come in handy and would work similarly so i upvoted your answer. Thank you!!!